# Django Haystack/Solr: Faceting on a model but show results only from a ForeignKey field

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack, faceted-search

I have two models in Django like follows(in pseudo code)

```
class Medicine(db.Model):
    field_1 = db.CharField()
    field_2 = db.CharField()

class Application(db.Model):
    field_1 = db.CharField()
    field_2 = db.CharField()
    medicine = db.ForeignKey(Medicine)
```

There is a 1:M. One medicine can have many applications.

I need to facet on the fields of `Application` but only show related `Medicine` objects.  Something like DISTINCT in SQL.

What would be the most straight forward way to accomplish this with haystack?

Do I make `SearchIndex` for `Medicine` or `Application`? If I make `SearchIndex` for `Application`, how do I detect/filter duplicate `Medicine` objects?

PS: I know there's Field Collapsing feature in dev releases of Solr, but I want to avoid doing that, becuase it is huge database and performance critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with the help of Daniel Lindsay(Haystack/pySolr author) on haystack mailing list.

```
from haystack import indexes

class Medicine(indexes.SearchIndex):
    field_1 = indexes.MultiValuedField(faceted=True)
    # Other field definitions


    def prepare_field_1(self, object):
        values = list()
        for app in object.applications.all():
            values.append(app.field_on_which_to_facet)
        return values

    # define "prepare_fieldname" methods for other fields in similar fashion.
```

Indexing takes some time as the data to be indexed is huge is huge, but worked like a charm.

Comment: How did you show the field values on the template? When you don't have a MultiValueField you usually use {{ result.object.afiledname }} but I'm not sure exactly how you do that in this case.

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. What I did was store the result snippet in a separete unindexed field defined as 'rendered = CharField(use_template=True, indexed=False)' which uses a template called as 'Medicine_rendered.txt'. In this template I put the html snippet for a single result object. Then in template simply render the {{ object_name.rendered }}.

For more details see: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#stored-indexed-fields

Comment: `MultiValueField` instead of `MultiValuedField`